# Avoiding State Changes in React Native - Is it Kosher?

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview, react-redux, textinput

Our team has been working with React Native for almost a year now, and one of the problems we ran into early on is the rendering speed. There are multiple components in our application that the user needs to drag, and state changes (combined with shouldComponentUpdate) were simply not fast enough to accomplish this goal.

We've gotten around this in two ways, and I was wondering to what extent these methods are kosher vs. hacks.

**Direct Manipulation and setNativeProps** - We've used setNativeProps so often, that we've created a Redux-like framework; however, instead of modifying the state, it uses setNativeProps for speed. The purpose of this was to expand setNativeProps beyond its use exclusively within the component; however, we do still use state changes whenever possible.

**Scrollview and TextInput** - We've managed to rotate and orient Scrollviews and TextInputs in such a way to work with setNativeProps, so that dragging content is smoother and more native, and text can be modified faster than a state change would allow.

We were wondering how kosher all of this is, as the React Native website only notes its complexity:

> setNativeProps is imperative and stores state in the native layer (DOM, UIView, etc.) and not within your React components, which makes your code more difficult to reason about.

Should we remodel our app?

Comment: Are you using immutables? What you are describing is definitely not good for react. The question is, shouldn't you be switching to native development instead? React-native is still a young product and not all its performance problems have been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setNativeProps` isn't recommended but I don't consider it a massive red flag if it's letting you achieve the quality you want. As the docs warn, it does make your code harder to reason about since it sets state in your native views that isn't in your React component hierarchy.

Two ways to tame this complexity are to reduce the number of different pieces of code that can set props via JSX or `setNativeProps` on a given component, and to gradually move away from `setNativeProps` and reduce rendering with `shouldComponentUpdate` and `PureComponent` instead.

Immutable data structures make it easier to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` as well as [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) selectors if you're using Redux. If your frequently rendered components have `render()` methods that create many elements, refactor groups of those elements out into pure components that don't necessarily need to be rendered as often. The [constant elements Babel transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-constant-elements/) will remove most of the cost of elements that never change by creating them only once; when React sees the same element across two consecutive `render()` passes it won't re-render the element the second time.